# Automated owncloud installation script

Tags: bash, linux, installer

Here is a shell script which installs and configure owncloud on a Debian server. It also installs apache2 and MySQL as dependencies and fail2ban with a specific rule for owncloud. Apache2 is also configured to use a self signed SSL certificate.

The script seems to work properly (everything is installed and works fine) my question is about the possible security issues that could be created:

- Is the ssl certificate correctly issued and installed?
- Is there a potential issue with the handling of mysql?
- Is there something else that I should see?

The official Github repo of this file is [here](https://github.com/michaelwiesing/Owncloud-Auto-Setup-for-Raspberry-Pi-2).

```
#!/bin/bash

#Some bash script optimization for robustness (More information: www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts/)
#Break if the script uses unset variables
set -o nounset
#Break if a command has a non-true return value
set -o errexit

echo_info () {
    echo "--------------------------------------"
    echo "| INFO: $1"
    echo "--------------------------------------"
}

echo_error () {
    echo "--------------------------------------"
    echo "| ERROR: $1"
    echo "--------------------------------------"
}

is_installed () {
    #Check if a package is installed (More information: https://askubuntu.com/questions/319307/reliably-check-if-a-package-is-installed-or-not)
    if dpkg --get-selections | grep -q "^$1[[:space:]]*install$" >/dev/null; then
        echo_error "$1 is already installed"
        exit 1
    fi
}

check_not_installed () {

    echo_info "Check if some package is already installed. If this is the case the script stops because it could not be performed without risc."

    is_installed apache2
    is_installed mysql-server-5.5
    is_installed owncloud
    is_installed fail2ban 

}

check_root () {
    if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
        echo_error "The script must be called as root user!"
        exit 1
    fi
}

install_owncloud () {

    cd /tmp

    #Automatic installation of owncloud (More information: https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:community&package=owncloud)

    echo_info "Add package repository"

    echo 'deb http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/8.2/Debian_8.0/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list

    wget -nv https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/8.2/Debian_8.0/Release.key -O Release.key
    apt-key add - < Release.key  
    rm Release.key  

    echo_info "Install owncloud"

    #Because a dependency the package mysql-server-5.5 is installed too. During the installation a prompt ask for the root password. The next lines set it with the value of the variable. (More information: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/perform_an_unattended_installation_of_a_debian_package.html)
    echo "mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password $mysqlRootPw" | debconf-set-selections
    echo "mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password_again password $mysqlRootPw" | debconf-set-selections

    apt-get update
    apt-get --assume-yes install owncloud

}

create_mysql_db () {

    echo_info "Create mysql database for owncloud"

    #Create a new database and user for owncloud (More information: http://www.bluepiccadilly.com/2011/12/creating-mysql-database-and-user-command-line-and-bash-script-automate-process)
    mysql=`which mysql`

    Q1="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $ocDb;"
    Q2="GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO $ocDbUser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '$ocDbUserPw';"
    Q3="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $ocDb.* TO $ocDbUser@localhost;"
    Q4="FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
    SQL="${Q1}${Q2}${Q3}${Q4}"

    $mysql -uroot -p$mysqlRootPw -e "$SQL"

}

patch_apache_filesize () {

    echo_info "Patch apache configuration"

    #Patch filesize in the htaccess (More Information: http://blog.webernetz.net/2015/07/15/yet-another-owncloud-installation-guide/)
    sed -i "s/php_value upload_max_filesize .*/php_value upload_max_filesize $maxFileSize/" /var/www/owncloud/.htaccess
    sed -i "s/php_value post_max_size .*/php_value post_max_size $maxFileSize/" /var/www/owncloud/.htaccess
    sed -i "s/php_value memory_limit .*/php_value memory_limit $maxFileSize/" /var/www/owncloud/.htaccess

    /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
}

configure_owncloud () {

    echo_info "Configure owncloud"

    #The data dir should not be under /var/www for security reasons, so the dir must be created (More information: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.1/admin_manual/configuration_server/harden_server.html)
    mkdir $ocDataDir
    chown -R ${htuser}:${htgroup} ${ocDataDir}/

    #Use the cli for first configuration (More information: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.1/admin_manual/installation/command_line_installation.html)
    cd /var/www/owncloud
    sudo -u $htuser php occ maintenance:install --database "mysql" --database-name "$ocDb"  --database-user "$ocDbUser" --database-pass "$ocDbUserPw" --admin-user "$ocAdminUser" --admin-pass "$ocAdminUserPw" --data-dir "$ocDataDir"

        #Add the hostname and ip to the trusted domains, so that it could be reached from outside (More Information: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.1/admin_manual/installation/installation_wizard.html?highlight=trusted_domains#label-trusted-domains)
    sed -i "/.*0 => 'localhost',/a \\    1 => '$hostname',\n    2 => '$ip'," /var/www/owncloud/config/config.php

    /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

}

install_fail2ban () {

    echo_info "Install fail2ban"

    apt-get --assume-yes install fail2ban

    #First configure the owncloud logfile
    logFileMasked=$(echo $logFile | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
    logTimezoneMasked=$(echo $logTimeZone | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
    sed -i "s/  'logtimezone' => 'UTC',/  'logtimezone' => '$logTimezoneMasked',\n  'logfile' => '$logFileMasked',\n  'loglevel' => '2',/" /var/www/owncloud/config/config.php

    touch $logFile
    chown ${htuser}:${htgroup} $logFile

    #Now configure fail2ban (More Information: http://www.rojtberg.net/711/secure-owncloud-server/, https://got-tty.org/archives/owncloud-6-sicherheit-durch-fail2ban.html)
    echo -e "[Definition]\nfailregex={\"app\":\"core\",\"message\":\"Login failed: user '.*' , wrong password, IP:<HOST>\",\"level\":2,\"time\":\".*\"}\n          {\"app\":\"core\",\"message\":\"Login failed: '.*' \(Remote IP: '<HOST>', X-Forwarded-For: '.*'\)\",\"level\":2,\"time\":\".*\"}\n          {\"reqId\":\".*\",\"remoteAddr\":\"<HOST>\",\"app\":\"core\",\"message\":\"Login failed: .*\",\"level\":2,\"time\":\".*\"}" > /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/owncloud.conf

    echo -e "[owncloud]\nenabled  = true\nfilter   = owncloud\nport     = http,https\nmaxretry = $maxRetry\nlogpath  = $logFile" >> /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

    /etc/init.d/fail2ban restart
}

enable_apache_ssl () {

    echo_info "Enable and compel apache ssl with default self-signed certifiacte of debian"

    #Uses the default self-signed certificate of debian (More information: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.1/admin_manual/installation/source_installation.html#enabling-ssl)
    a2enmod ssl
    a2ensite default-ssl

    #Force https for every connection (More information: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.1/admin_manual/configuration_server/harden_server.html)
    a2enmod headers
    sed -i "/.*<VirtualHost.*/a \\\tServerName $hostname\n\tRedirect permanent \/ https:\/\/$hostname\/" /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    sed -i "/.*<VirtualHost.*/a \\\t\tServerName $hostname\n\t\tHeader always add Strict-Transport-Security \"max-age=15768000\"" /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

    /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
}

enable_apc_cache () {

    echo_info "Enable apc cache"
    #Install and configure apcu (More information: https://owncloud.org/blog/making-owncloud-faster-through-caching/)
    apt-get --assume-yes install php-apc
    sed -i "s/);/  'memcache.local' => '\\\OC\\\Memcache\\\APCu',\n);/" /var/www/owncloud/config/config.php

    /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
}

#Read in the variables in an interacive mode. Too make it a little more comfortable, the following functions need to be defined.

#Read a value and set the default value as input (More Information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642585/read-a-variable-in-bash-with-a-default-value)
read_value () {
    unset value
    read -e -i $1 value
}

#Hide the input and mask it with stars (More Information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923435/how-do-i-echo-stars-when-reading-password-with-read) (Part of the read_pw function)
read_pw_loop_masked () {
    unset password
    while IFS= read -p "$prompt" -r -s -n 1 char
    do
        if [[ $char == $'\0' ]]
        then
            break
        fi
        prompt='*'
        password+="$char"
    done
    echo
}

#Ask for the password two times (Part of the read_pw function)
read_pw_loop_compare () {
    prompt="Enter Password:"
    read_pw_loop_masked
    password1=$password
    prompt="Reenter Password:"
    read_pw_loop_masked
    password2=$password
}

#Loop the password question until the two values match (Part of the read_pw function)
read_pw_loop () {
    read_pw_loop_compare
    while [ "$password1" != "$password2" ] ; do
        echo "Please retype, because the passwords did not match."
        read_pw_loop_compare    
    done
    password=$password1
}

#Main function for reading a password
read_pw () {
    echo $*
    read_pw_loop

}

ask_for_values () {
    echo_info "The script now ask for some values that are necessary for the installation."
    #You can customize the default values of the variables here or set a static value

    #Hostname and IP (the command retrieve this information automatically in the case that only the standard ethernet interface is installed)
    hostname=`hostname`
    echo "Please enter the hostname (The automatically indentified value is filled in, but you can easily change it if it is wrong.):"
    read_value $hostname
    hostname=$value
    ip=`hostname -I`
    echo "Please enter the ip of the outside interface (The automatically indentified value is filled in, but you can easily change it if it is wrong.):"
    read_value $ip
    ip=$value

    #Mysql configuration
    read_pw "Please enter a password for the root user of mysql:"
    mysqlRootPw=$password

    echo "Please enter the name of the mysql database for owncloud (The default value is filled in, but you can easily change it.):"
    read_value owncloud
    ocDb=$value

    echo "Please enter the name of the mysql user for owncloud (The default value is filled in, but you can easily change it.):"
    read_value owncloud
    ocDbUser=$value

    read_pw "Please enter a password for the owncloud user of mysql:"
    ocDbUserPw=$password

    #Apache2 configuration
    echo "Please enter the maximal size of files that could be uploaded to owncloud (The default value is filled in, but you can easily change it.):"
    read_value 1024M
    maxFileSize=$value
    #Typically user and group filled static
    htuser='www-data'
    htgroup='www-data'

    #Owncloud configuration

    echo "Please enter the name of the owncloud administrator(The default value is filled in, but you can easily change it.):"
    read_value admin
    ocAdminUser=$value

    read_pw "Please enter a password for the owncloud administrator:"
    ocAdminUserPw=$password

    echo "Please enter the path to the folder for files of owncloud (The default value is filled in, but you can easily change it.):"
    read_value /home/owncloud
    ocDataDir=$value

    #Fail2Ban
    logTimeZone=`cat /etc/timezone`
    echo "Please enter the time zone for the owncloud log (The default value is filled in, but you can easily change it.):"
    read_value $logTimeZone
    logTimeZone=$value

    echo "Please enter the path where owncloud log should be saved (The default value is filled in, but you can easily change it.):"
    read_value /var/log/owncloud.log
    logFile=$value

    echo "Please enter the max fails until fail2ban ban an ip (The default value is filled in, but you can easily change it.):"
    read_value 3
    maxRetry=$value

}

generate_self_signed_certificate () {

    echo_info "The script now generate a self signed certificate with a self created ca. For it the script ask for many values. The most necessary you can fill with a dot if you do not have a valid value. The 'extra' attributes you could skip with enter. Only the pass phrase for own-ca.key and the common name are important. The first value is the password for your ca, please type in a strong password and take a note of it. You will need it at least some seconds later. The common name must befit the hostname and you must type it in two times."

    #Generate a self signed certificate with a self created ca (More Information: https://thomas-leister.de/internet/eine-eigene-openssl-ca-erstellen-und-self-signed-certe-ausstellen/)
    # This was necessary because otherwise Apps like DAVdroid didn't work with the owncloud (More Information: https://davdroid.bitfire.at/faq/entry/importing-a-certificate)

    #Create a new ca
    mkdir /etc/ssl/ownca/
    cd /etc/ssl/ownca/
    openssl genrsa -aes256 -out own-ca.key 2048
    #Create the root certificate that is valid for 10 years
    openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -extensions v3_ca -key own-ca.key -days 3650 -out own-ca-root.pem -sha512
    #Create a client certificate that is valid for 10 years and sign it
    openssl genrsa -out self-signed-cert.key 4096
    openssl req -new -key self-signed-cert.key -out self-signed-cert.csr -sha512
    openssl x509 -req -in self-signed-cert.csr -CA own-ca-root.pem -CAkey own-ca.key -CAcreateserial -out self-signed-cert.pem -days 3650 -sha512
    rm self-signed-cert.csr
    mv ./self-signed-cert.pem ../certs
    mv ./self-signed-cert.key ../private
    mv ./own-ca-root.pem ../certs

}

install_self_signed_certificate () {
    sed -i "s/      SSLCertificateFile  \/etc\/ssl\/certs\/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem/       SSLCertificateFile  \/etc\/ssl\/certs\/self-signed-cert.pem/" /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
    sed -i "s/      SSLCertificateKeyFile \/etc\/ssl\/private\/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key/       SSLCertificateKeyFile \/etc\/ssl\/private\/self-signed-cert.key/" /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
    sed -i "s/      #SSLCertificateChainFile \/etc\/apache2\/ssl.crt\/server-ca.crt/        SSLCertificateChainFile \/etc\/ssl\/certs\/own-ca-root.pem/" /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
    /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
}

#You can customize the called functions here (you are responsible for looking for dependencies between them)
check_root
check_not_installed
ask_for_values
generate_self_signed_certificate
echo_info "Now the unattended part of the setup is started."
install_owncloud
create_mysql_db
patch_apache_filesize
configure_owncloud
install_fail2ban
enable_apache_ssl
enable_apc_cache
install_self_signed_certificate

echo_info "FINISH"
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Naming

Some of the function names could be improved, for example this one:

> ```
> is_installed () {
>     #Check if a package is installed (More information: https://askubuntu.com/questions/319307/reliably-check-if-a-package-is-installed-or-not)
>     if dpkg --get-selections | grep -q "^$1[[:space:]]*install$" >/dev/null; then
>         echo_error "$1 is already installed"
>         exit 1
>     fi
> }
> ```

I expect a function named `is_X` to behave like a boolean,
so that I can build conditional statements with it.
But this is not that kind of function,
it validates something or else exits the program.
I'd name this `verify_not_installed` or similar.

#### Other minor issues

> ```
> if dpkg --get-selections | grep -q "^$1[[:space:]]*install$" >/dev/null; then
> ```

You don't need to redirect the output of `grep -q`, the `-q` flag already takes care of that.

---

> ```
> echo_error "$1 is already installed"
> exit 1
> ```

Every time you `echo_error`, you also `exit 1`.
So you could move the `exit 1` inside the function,
and then probably rename it (I usually call it `fatal`).

---

> ```
> echo 'deb http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/8.2/Debian_8.0/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list
>
> wget -nv https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/8.2/Debian_8.0/Release.key -O Release.key
> ```

The base URL is common in both of these commands,
so I would put it in a variable to make it easy to change later if needed.

---

> ```
> mysql=`which mysql`
> ```

Backticks are archaic, use `$(...)` instead.

---

> ```
> Q1="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $ocDb;"
> Q2="GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO $ocDbUser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '$ocDbUserPw';"
> Q3="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $ocDb.* TO $ocDbUser@localhost;"
> Q4="FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
> SQL="${Q1}${Q2}${Q3}${Q4}"
> ```

This is a tedious and fragile way to construct a longer string.
You could pass a here-document directly to `mysql`:

```
mysql -uroot -p$mysqlRootPw <<EOF
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $ocDb;
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO $ocDbUser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '$ocDbUserPw';
...
EOF
```

---

> ```
> sed -i "s/php_value upload_max_filesize .*/php_value upload_max_filesize $maxFileSize/" /var/www/owncloud/.htaccess
> sed -i "s/php_value post_max_size .*/php_value post_max_size $maxFileSize/" /var/www/owncloud/.htaccess
> sed -i "s/php_value memory_limit .*/php_value memory_limit $maxFileSize/" /var/www/owncloud/.htaccess
> ```

This overwrites the `/var/www/owncloud/.htaccess` three times. 
You can perform multiple replacements in a single `sed` call,
and overwrite the file only once:

```
sed -i \
  -e "s/php_value upload_max_filesize .*/php_value upload_max_filesize $maxFileSize/" \
  -e "s/php_value post_max_size .*/php_value post_max_size $maxFileSize/" \
  -e "s/php_value memory_limit .*/php_value memory_limit $maxFileSize/" \
  /var/www/owncloud/.htaccess
```

---

> ```
> echo -e "[Definition]\nfailregex={\"app\":\"core\",\"message\":\"Login failed: user '.*' , wrong password, IP:<HOST>\",\"level\":2,\"time\":\".*\"}\n          {\"app\":\"core\",\"message\":\"Login failed: '.*' \(Remote IP: '<HOST>', X-Forwarded-For: '.*'\)\",\"level\":2,\"time\":\".*\"}\n          {\"reqId\":\".*\",\"remoteAddr\":\"<HOST>\",\"app\":\"core\",\"message\":\"Login failed: .*\",\"level\":2,\"time\":\".*\"}" > /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/owncloud.conf
> ```

This extremely long line is unreadable.
Consider using a here-document instead:

```
cat <<"EOF" > /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/owncloud.conf
[Definition]
failregex={"app":"core","message":"Login failed: user '.*' , wrong password, IP:<HOST>","level":2,"time":".*"}
          {"app":"core","message":"Login failed: '.*' \(Remote IP: '<HOST>', X-Forwarded-For: '.*'\)","level":2,"time":".*"}
          {"reqId":".*","remoteAddr":"<HOST>","app":"core","message":"Login failed: .*","level":2,"time":".*"}
EOF
```